# Implications of convergence in probability?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

Let $||.||$ indicate the Euclidean norm. Let $\theta_0$ be a specific value of the parameter $\theta \in \Theta\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and $G_n$ be a random vector-valued function 
$$
G_n : \Theta  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^b
$$
Let $\hat{\theta}_n$ be an estimate of $\theta_0$. 
Assume 
\begin{equation}
\text{(a) }\limsup_{n\rightarrow  \infty}  \mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{||\theta-\theta_0||> \delta}\frac{1}{||G_n(\theta)||}>M_\epsilon\right)<\epsilon \text{, } \forall \epsilon>0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\text{(b) }\lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}  \mathbb{P}\left(||G_n(\hat{\theta}_n)||>\epsilon\right)=0 \text{, } \forall \epsilon>0
\end{equation}
Questions:

(1) Does (b) imply $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb P\left(\frac{1}{||G_n(\hat{\theta}_n)||} > M_\epsilon\right)=1$ $\forall \epsilon > 0$?

(2) Do (a) and (b) imply
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{||G_n(\hat{\theta}_n)||} > M_\epsilon \geq \sup_{||\theta-\theta_0||> \delta}\frac{1}{||G_n(\theta)||}\right)\geq 1-2 \epsilon \text{, } \forall \epsilon>0?
\end{equation}

Comment: What is $M_\varepsilon$?

Comment: It is a number depending on epsilon.